# Android Realm openTransaction doesn't return

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to update Realm in my app from version 0.85 to version 4.1.1. In some cases, realm.beginTransaction doesn't return. I tried to replace it by realm.executeTransaction with no effect. Here are the verbose logs of Realm:

```
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsSchemaInfo_nativeCreateFromList
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsRealmConfig_nativeCreate
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsRealmConfig_nativeSetInMemory -1605354496
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsRealmConfig_nativeEnableChangeNotification -1605354496
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsRealmConfig_nativeSetSchemaConfig -1605354496
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetSharedRealm -1605354496
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetSchemaInfo -1605349584
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeSetAutoRefresh -1605349584
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeRegisterSchemaChangedCallback -1605349584
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed -1605349584
V/REALM_JNI:  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeBeginTransaction -1605349584
```

So it looks to me that Relam is stuck while calling SharedRealm.nativeBeginTransaction, which matches what I saw when debugging.

Here's my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath ('io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
        }
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And my module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

// increment code and change version name on every released build
def code = 93
def version = "1.1.8"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode code
        versionName "$version"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV", "false"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            multiDexEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV", "true"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.4-android'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 and had to enable D8 for building

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: `realm.beginTransaction()` doesn't return if it's blocked by a write transaction that is occurring on a different thread at the same time.

Comment: Does that mean that it was not the case in earlier versions of Realm?

Comment: Well technically it should have, although it wasn't blocking across processes (which could result in undefined behavior). A possibility is that the notifications are evaluated a bit slowly in your schema, which can be fixed by removing a bidirectional link and replacing it with @LinkingObjects

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I found out that the transaction was blocked by a RealmResults.clear() call. Replacing it by deleteAllFromRealm solved the issue.

Comment: I think that throws UnsupportedOperationException` and execute should cancel the transaction, yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue happened because realm.beginTransaction() doesn't return if it's blocked by a write transaction that is occurring on a different thread at the same time. In my case, this was due to a call to RealmResults.clear(). It was fixed by replacing it by deleteAllFromRealm()